# Pass a JSON object inside the function

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to pass a JSON object as an argument in the first function, then pass the same JSON object into second function from the first function?  Do I need to extract it first, then stringify before pass it to the second function?

Thanks

For example, I have the following JSON object

```
var client=[{"clientID":"1234",
             "businessName":"ABC Corporation",
             "legalName":"DCF Inc.",
             "clientName":"John"}];
```

I pass this Client JSON object into the first function:

```
function saveClient(clients){

// inside this function, I want to pass this whole Client object into the
// second function     

    function showClient(clients){
    // so inside this function, I can parse this Client object to get the 
    // string and value
    var clientID=client.clientID;
    var businessName=client.businessName;
    .....
    .....
    }
}
```

Comment: That's *NOT* a "JSON Object" (there's no such thing).  It's a JavaScript object.  Also, what's the problem?  How are you calling these functions?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, just pass the array element you want (assuming `i` is the index of the client of interest):

```
showClient(clients[i]);
```

There is definitely no need to "stringify" or anything like that, since you're working entirely within Javascript here.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and not simply correcting him for calling it a JSON object.